# Modify a field within a cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it possible to edit a field inside a cookie using javascript? The cookie looks like this

```
cookie_session=[{"id":"1526","username":"test","email":"test@test.com"}]
```

For example, is it possible to edit the value of the field username?

I'm trying to use

`document.cookie="Field=myValue"`

But when i use it, it sets the whole value of the cookie to myValue instead of a certain field within it.

Also, would it be possible to parse the value of username to use it later for a POST request?

Comment: Why would you want to extract the user name for a request, the cookie is already sent along?

Comment: I want to be able to read the value of a field in the cookie.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003823/javascript-getcookie-functions

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A cookie is simply a string.  You are storing javascript objects inside of a cookie.  In order to modify a single part of the object, you will need to decode the JSON, edit the property, and re-encode the object back to a string to store it in the cookie.

btw - cookies were not meant to store javascript objects.  If you don't need the data on the server, then you are better off using local/session storage.  There are jQuery plugins which allow those mechanisms to work in a cross-browser friendly fashion.

EDIT: an example can be found here: [Pure Javascript - store object in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344531/pure-javascript-store-object-in-cookie)

Comment: What about parsing a certain field within the cookie?

Comment: So since a cookie is simply a string, it has no fields.  Now in your case, the string happens to be a string representing a javascript object (JSON).  You must first `parse` the JSON back into a real javascript object.  At that point, you can change the properties on the object.  Then you will have to `stringify` the object back into JSON and save it back in the cookie.

Comment: That sounds really hard, i don't know much about javascript unfortunately. I don't know if it's possible but what i want to do is: when a user visits a page, his username is only stored in a cookie, i read that cookie and username, use it as a variable to send a POST request based on their username. Would that be even possible?

Comment: You don't really need to know JavaScript in order to understand the difference between an object and a string.  Also, I hope you don't have anything important taking place with this username, as your system could get hacked by a 3rd grader.  You need to use proper authentication lookup... which is way beyond the scope of this post.  In the mean time, do research on JSON, strings, and objects. Here's a jsfiddle explaining it all: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/RNMWs/