# How to store cache values of audio file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm using an audio (`.swf`) file in my site, which has two options: AUDIO ON and AUDIO OFF. I can on and off the audio. The problem  is that audio is not stopping. It is playing repeatedly. Can anyone help me?

The other problem is, whenever I reload any page the audio file plays from the start. I want it to be played from where the audio was previously stopped.

EDIT: Added code from comment

```
<audio id="main_audio" <?php echo $autoplaynf;?> preload="auto" loop="loop"> 
   <embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true" src="audio.mp3" /> 
</audio>
```

Comment: [What have you alredy tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I don't know how to stop audio. I was struck-up there. How can I stop audio file after completion of the music?

Comment: That's clear, but you should show some code what you have done already. We do not have a crystal ball to see your code. You can also create a fiddle at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a testcase of your problem and post a link here so we can see what's the problem

Comment: <audio id="main_audio" <?php echo $autoplaynf;?> preload="auto" loop="loop">
<embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true" src="audio.mp3" />
</audio>

Comment: When ever I reload it should hold the cache value at where it is previously paused and it should play from that point of time. It should not play from the beginning.

Comment: Is it possible? or we cannot do like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page your audio will start from the beginning. If you really need to start from where you left you must store the playback position in a cookie. It could also be done by storing the position on the server but it would not work if the connection is lost while the entire audio file has been cached.

1. Use the `timeupdate` event from the audio tag will allow you to know when the current playback position has changed. This playback position should be changed
2. Use a cookie to store the playback position. If you use different audio files, you could store the audio filename with the cookie as well so you can distinguish if the audio file has changed or not.
3. When the page is loaded and the cookie exists for the specific audio file, start from the playback position in the cookie, otherwise start from the beginning.

Provided that you have this code:

```
<audio id="main_audio" <?php echo $autoplaynf;?> preload="auto" loop="loop"> 
   <embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="true" src="audio.mp3" /> 
</audio>
```

You can add javascript (not sure if you use jQuery) to perform the above actions. Note that this must be executed only after the audio tag has been loaded. Note that this is pseudo code only. Try to use it as a guideline to get your thing done.

```
// when page is loaded do the following actions
var atag = document.getElementById("main_audio");
atag.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdateEvent, false);

// check if coockie exists
var timePos = readCookie();
atag.currentPos = timePos;

function timeUpdateEvent(event) {
    // get time position from audio tag
    // store cookie
}

function readCookie() {
    // read the cookie and return time value
    // of cookie does not exist return a timevalue
    // that will let the audio start from the beginning
}
```

For storing, reading and deleting cookies I refere to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11344672/474535) on SO. Probably there are more examples for that.