# JQuery: retrieve object from cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, websocket

I want to store my websocket  connection in cookies. I use `$.cookie('ws', ws)`; in firebug ws looks like:

```
WebSocket {binaryType: "blob", extensions: "", protocol: "", onclose: function, onerror: null…}
    URL: "wss://localhost:5432/"
    binaryType: "blob"
    bufferedAmount: 0
    extensions: ""
    onclose: function (m) {
    onerror: null
    onmessage: function (m) {
    onopen: function () {
    protocol: ""
    readyState: 0
    url: "wss://localhost:5432/"
    __proto__: WebSocket
}
```

***Problem:***

When I get my websocket connection from cookies it looks like: `[object WebSocket]` and I can't pull anything from it.

***Question:*** How can I convert `[object WebSocket]` to normal websocket object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie stores *text*, attempting to store an object will only store its string representation which is the useless character sequence "`[object WebSocket]`".

Instead store the relevant (text) properties, read them back and reconstruct the object from scratch.

Comment: has I ability somehow store objects in the client side?

Comment: No, you have to store the textual details needed to reconstruct the object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344531/pure-javascript-store-object-in-cookie