# How can set cookies in Javascript using objects

Tags: javascript, object, cookies

I have been doing web design for a while but, I never have to create cookies, I know the cookie value has to be a string, how can I take an object to set cookies on Javascript.

Comment: This post [Pure Javascript - store object in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344531/pure-javascript-store-object-in-cookie) might be what you're looking for. Also may be a duplicate :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure Javascript - store object in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344531/pure-javascript-store-object-in-cookie)

Comment: Use  `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` on reparsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can take an object.

res.cookie('token', jwtToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, maxAge:900000 })